# How to implement real time application pure

Tags: php, node.js, sockets, real-time

I am actually developing application for bank cash management.. It must be **real-time**... Once there is a change in db it must be sent to the client... I don't want to use long polling or ajax etc... (Because It puts load on the server by repeating requests)...

Cant use nodejs or other server related technology... (Not installed in server)... Question is that I want to **develop server pure in php**... Can anyone post code and give the details about it... Searched internet a lot but nothing there... Suggestions will be appreciated

[Edit]

I am putting my angularjs code for long polling here:

```
function dataCtrl($scope, $timeout, Data) {
                $scope.data = [];

                (function tick() {
                    $scope.data = Data.query(function(){
                        $timeout(tick, 1000);
                    });
                })();
            };
```

and I call tick function in the following code

```
$http.get('url').success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                  data.response = data;
                  $('.serverStatus').text(data.response.message);
                  data.calls++;
                  $timeout(poller, 1000);
                });
              };
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "real time application" or "realtime" here? I have the impression you actually mean something else here than what is usually referred to as "realtime constraint".. Apart from that: why should ajax long calls put load on a server? They are idle until a reply is sent. You can take a look at web sockets for push notifications, but that does not really change the basic architecture underneath.

Comment: I mean just like facebook... when there is a comment/like by one user, update sent to other user at that time

Comment: You can't find anything because you can't do it in php without javascript.

Comment: I have used javascript comet/ajax.. but it sends request from my browser to server every second(or time interval).. but i only want that browser will get data when there is a change received from server

Comment: Sorry, but this is impossible to do, since the technology does not offer such thing. A browser is _not_ a server, so it cannot be contacted from outside. Also this would violate the network topology in most cases.

Comment: then how did other applications work? What thing they have implemented?

Comment: Ajax long polls are the right choice here, or mentioned web sockets. Same basic principle, and no, they do _not_ send a request every second. They hold open a channel for as long as the server allows, then reopen it. That does not add much load to a server, since those channels are inactive, except when used. There is no way around that without modifying a browser by means of a plugin.

Comment: Doesn't it put a lot of load on server... I will be requesting alot even if there is no activity on the server...  Suppose we have one million users each of them will be sending request from their browser

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must use sockets in your application... You can find Php socket library named Rachet over here
http://socketo.me/

There must be socket connection between users. So socket will listen until the data comes